# Debug reference's code in MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, monodevelop

In Visual Studio when I'm debugging a project if I go in to code that's a reference to the project VS will try to find the reference's source code and symbols so that you can step through the code. How do I so this in MonoDevelop on OSX when trying to debug a MonoMac application?

Comment: Your description on Visual Studio is not accurrate. Without symbols and source files, even Visual Studio could not show you the references' source code.

Comment: Meanwhile, MonoDevelop's debugging is not equivalent to Visual Studio's, http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Debugger

Comment: that is true, will update the question. MonoDevelop does have access in this case though since the other project is built in it as well

Comment: Lex Li: The hard debugger has been deprecated for many years, that pages is very out of date.

Comment: Samuel: We'll need more info. What OS? What kind of project? What version of MonoDevelop/Mono? Are the referenced projects in the same solution? Did you reference them as projects or as files?

Comment: will add though I found the answer myself so will self answer afterward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In preferences under the MonoDevelop menu there is a settings section called "Debugger". In there is a settings called "Debug project code only; do not set into framework code" Unchecking that will tell MonoDevelop to go to other assemblies if it has the debug