# Browsing the framework code in MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I already have "stepping into framework code" working fine. Now I want to browse this code with F12 (Go to Declaration), like in Visual Studio with some add-ins. Is it possible in MonoDevelop?

Comment: You completely miss the fact that debugging Mono source code in MonoDevelop has been supported quite a long time, though its setup varies from flavor to flavor. Forget about Microsoft's Windows bits and search on Google with proper keywords.

Comment: @LexLi, I don't get you. I tried to search stuff as "monodevelop browse framework code" etc, also looked up in add-ins, but no luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761946/debug-references-code-in-monodevelop and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864542/what-are-the-first-steps-for-tracking-down-a-exception-triggered-in-the-mono-asp

Comment: @LexLi sorry, but as I said, I _can_ debug the framework code, the problem is browsing it during editing.

Comment: no Add-in yet. But you can write one if you know Roslyn.